# enable or diable link based on condition in wicket framework

Tags: java, wicket

I have one requirement in WICKET framework.

I would like to enable and disable link based on if else condition. Anybody can give suggestion to how to archive it?

Here is the sample code:

```
Link<OrderAssetAncillaryListEntry> getDesc = new Link<OrderAssetAncillaryListEntry>(
            "descLink", new Model(oale)) {
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            final OrderAssetAncillaryListEntry oale = this.getModelObject();
            String[] scrids = {oale.getScrid()};

            try {

                byte[] content = getReportBytes(scrids);
                IResourceStream resourceStream = new ByteArrayResourceStream(
                        content, "application/vnd.ms-excel");

                getRequestCycle().setRequestTarget(
                        new ResourceStreamRequestTarget(resourceStream) {

                            @Override
                            public String getFileName() {
                                return oale.getShowCode() + "_desc.xls";
                            }
                        });


            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("Unable to fetch Description Report file", e);
            } 
        }
    };
    // add label
    getDesc.add(new Label("descLinkLabel", "Description"));
    return getDesc;
```

Answer (score 2):

`#isEnabled ()` is called many times per request. It is better to override `#onConfigure ()` and use `setEnabled ()` in it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you override `Link#isEnabled()` and evaluate your condition there.

Answer (score 0):

You have different options to do so:

```
    //Business logic turning someCondition true or false
   final boolean someCondition = verifyBusiness();

    Link<String> testLink = new Link<String>("test", Model.of("someProperty")){


        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {//Option 1
            if (someCondition){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            //business logic
        }
    };

    //OR use something as below

    testLink.setEnabled(someCondition ? true : false);//Option 2
```

```
    private boolean verifyBusiness(){

        return true; //Whatever you want to return based upon your logic
    }
```